# Effectivelly using Compile for calculate a Unitary transformation

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra, physics, compile, eigenvalues

I am new to Mathematica, and this is my first post, so if my question is not clear enough, I would be glad to read the comments and edit my question to add more information.

### The problem

I need to calculate the unitary matrix $U$ that **diagonalizes** a `SparseArray` $iA$  and it columns are **sorted by the eigenvalues** such that [ by $^\dagger$ I mean `ConjugateTranspose` ]:

$$ U \ iA \ U^\dagger \ = \ \left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 E_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0   \\ 
 0 & E_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0& 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & -E_1 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -E_2 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0  & \ddots  \\ \end{array} \right) $$

I made a code that worked fine and spent about 0.5 seconds for a matrix of size $1004\times1004$. In the code I define my matrix $iA(k,n,J,\kappa,h)$  of size $(2n+4)\times(2n+4)$, then I use Eigensystem and apply *mySort* to sort the eigenvectors in the way I wanted and formed my unitary matrix with this eigenvectors. I need it to be faster because I want to examine how the coefficients of the unitary matrix $U$ depend upon the parameters in the interval $\{ 0\leq k < \pi \, , \, 0< \kappa \leq 1 \, , \, 0< h\leq 1 \}$, for $J=1$ and optimally for large $n$. In practice, I would like to test for about $100$ values of $k$, $10$ for $\kappa$ and $10$ values for $h$; so I will need to calculate about $10.000$ of matrices.

- **Q1: There is a more efficient way to calculate this Unitary matrix?**

The first problem is that the Mathematica automatically convert my SparseArray, to a normal one, since I want to calculate **all** the eigenvectors (which is needed). Return the standard warning:

```
Eigensystem::arh: Because finding 1004 out of the 1004 eigenvalues and/or eigenvectors is likely to be faster with dense matrix methods, the sparse input matrix will be converted...
```

I try to use other `Methods` for the `Eigensystem`, but neither of this is optimized for calculating all eigenvector. From what I have seen in others post this would be the maximum performance if I indeed wanted all eigenvectors, then I try to reduce the numbers of eigenvectors that I want. Given the symmetry of the matrix $iA$ I also tried to calculate just *half* of the eigenvectors, corresponding to only positive eigenvalues, using `Method->{"FEAST","Interval"->{0.,10.}}` but I do not see any time reduction.

- **Q2: There is a more efficient method for calculating all eigenvectors corresponding to positive eigenvalues?**

I also want to put this whole code inside a function that takes values $(k,n,J,\kappa,h)$ and return the unitary matrix I have tried to use the `Compile`, but the `Compile` return some errors related with the Type of the matrix

```
Compile::cptype: N is not supported for type None; evaluation will use the uncompiled function.
```

and

```
Compile::cplist: SortBy[Compile`FunctionVariable$7579,First] should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function.
```

I have read the documentation for `Compile`, and I don't know if it is appropriate for this kind of problem, but I was thinking that it would speed up the calculation. From what I have seen, the `Compile` can not return a matrix as an output *(it is true?)*, but for me would be enough to analyse element by element of the matrix.

- **Q3: Can I use `Compile` in this example? Or at least use it to generate a compiled function that outputs the $ij$-th element ?**

### My code

As I described above, my code has a few fundamental elements: the matrix itself, the sorting procedure and the code to calculate the unitary matrix.

- The Matrix

```
    iA[k_, n_, J_, κ_, h_] :=   SparseArray[{

{i_, i_} ->      If[1 < i < 2*n + 4,  If[OddQ[i], -2*κ*Sin[k], 2*κ*Sin[k]], 0], 
{i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 ->  If[(i == 1 || j == 1) || (i == 2*n + 4 || j == 2*n + 4), If[i == 1 || i == 2*n + 4, (-I)*h, I*h],  If[EvenQ[Min[i, j]],  2*J*Cos[k/2]*(i - j)*I, (-(i - j))*I*J]], 
{i_, j_} /;  Abs[i - j] == 2 -> If[(i == 1 || j == 1) || (i == 2*n + 4 || j == 2*n + 4), 0, If[OddQ[i], 2*κ*Sin[k/2], -2*κ*Sin[k/2]]]}

, {2*n + 4, 2*n + 4}];
```

- MySort

```
mySort = (Transpose[ Chop[Flatten[{Drop[SortBy[#1, First], Length[#1]/2],Reverse[Take[SortBy[#1, First], Length[#1]/2]]}, 1]]] & )[Transpose[#1]] & ;
```

- The code for the calculate the Unitary matrix
  The code that works but is slow:

```
U[k_, n_, J_, κ_, h_] = mySort[Eigensystem[N[iA[k, n, J, κ, h][[2]]]]]
```

and the code with  `Compile`  that don't even work

```
U = Compile[  { {k, _Real, 0}, {n, _Integer, 0}, {J, _Real, 0}, {κ, _Real, 0}, {h, _Real, 0} , {m, _Integer, 0} , {y, _Integer, 0} },  mySort@Eigensystem@N@Normal@ iA[k, n, J, κ, h]  , CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
```

### Additional Info

- The matrix $iA$ is a Hermitian and pentadiagonal of the form [ it has only three distinct $2\times 2$ blocks the repeates across the matrix] :

> ! $ iA = \left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  0 & -i h & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  i h & 2 \kappa  \sin (k) & -2 i J \cos \left(\frac{k}{2}\right) & -2 \kappa  \sin \left(\frac{k}{2}\right) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 2 i J \cos \left(\frac{k}{2}\right) & -2 \kappa  \sin (k) & i J & 2 \kappa  \sin \left(\frac{k}{2}\right) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & -2 \kappa  \sin \left(\frac{k}{2}\right) & -i J & 2 \kappa  \sin (k) & -2 i J \cos \left(\frac{k}{2}\right) & -2 \kappa  \sin \left(\frac{k}{2}\right) & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 2 \kappa  \sin \left(\frac{k}{2}\right) & 2 i J \cos \left(\frac{k}{2}\right) & -2 \kappa  \sin (k) & i J & 2 \kappa  \sin \left(\frac{k}{2}\right) & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & -2 \kappa  \sin \left(\frac{k}{2}\right) & -i J & 2 \kappa  \sin (k) & -2 i J \cos \left(\frac{k}{2}\right) & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \kappa  \sin \left(\frac{k}{2}\right) & 2 i J \cos \left(\frac{k}{2}\right) & -2 \kappa  \sin (k) & i h \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -i h & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) $

- I also don't know if the way I defined the $iA$ matrix and $mySort$ is the most efficient, but at least I have tested I lot and they work.
- The spectrum of $iA$ has a energy gap for all $k$ but for $k=0$.
- The matrix $iA$ has a symmetric spectrum of eigenvalues (i.e. if $E$ is a eigenvalue, then $-E$ will also be).
- I do not know a relation between the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalues $E$ e $-E$, but if someone has any hint I would appreciate a lot!
- If it is not clear, I want to calculate the coefficients of $U$ as a function of $(k,\kappa,h)$ for fixed $n$ and $J$. I want to see which coefficients are more relevant [biggest absolute value] in the regime of $k \to 0$.  Then I will plot how those $U_{i,j}$ depends upon each parameter, and hopefully I with figure an analytic dependence in that regime ( expect a linear behaviour in $k$, but no hint in the $\kappa$ and $h$ dependence).

Comment: Welcome! Interesting first question :) If one matrix takes 0.5 seconds, and you want to run it 10K times, why not just wait for a little less than the length of a movie?

Comment: @CATrevillian Becaue "Each desire once fulfilled immediately begets another. " ;)

Comment: @CATrevillian good point, perhaps this isn't a real big issue after all but would be nice to see if I am missing something  :)